# can i use ADAL(Active Directory Authentication Library) for AWS hosted ASP.Net MVC application using ADFS for authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, adfs, adal, adfs3.0, adfs4.0

We are planning to build a web application which will use ADFS for authentication. The web application will be hosted on an AWS instance but will be talking to on-premises or cloud ADFS.

can I use ADAL(Active Directory Authentication Library) for federating authentication and saving authentication context in this scenario? if yes is there any drawbacks?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "cloud ADFS" you mean ADFS in a VM in the cloud?

ADAL is for mobile and native devices.

Normally a web application will use OWIN e.g. like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/ad-fs-development).

If you are not using ADFS 4.0, then use WS-Fed or SAML as per [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=active-directory&type=&language=).

These are for Azure AD but the principles are the same.